# typedef struct <struct_name> vs simply typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, declaration, typedef

```
typedef struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;
```

```
typedef struct{
    int data;
    Node *next;
}Node;
```

What is the difference between these two, i.e between `struct Node <name>` and `Node <name>`?
Using the second one gives an error.

I am a bit new to C and I have seen the first one used when it is necessary to define the same struct inside the struct definition. Does it actually define the same struct or is it a different struct being defined?

Comment: Second one won't work if you need  self-referential structs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C, an identifier need to be declared before use. An identifier may be a variable name, a struct tag name, a typedef, a function name, etc. Without a declaration the compiler cannot possibly know what an identifier refers to.

In your first snippet, `struct Node` alone declares `Node` as a `struct`. Since the type is already declared (but its defintion is still incomplete, this is called an "incomplete type"), it can be used in limited ways, including declaring a member of a pointer to the type. The definition of the struct is complete at the point of the closing bracket.

In the second snippet, an unnamed struct is declared and at the point you use `Node`, there is no previous declaration and hence the compiler cannot figure out what the identifier `Node` refers to, hence it cannot be used in the way as shown in your snippet.

Comment: So inside the main function, is using `struct Node <name> = {<content>}` the same thing as using `Node <name> = {<content>}`? I.e are both the instances of the same struct?

I am only taking about the struct in the first codeblock. Not the one which causes compilation error.

Comment: Since the second snippet does not compile at all, it is not clear what you're exactly refering to. If you mean after both `typedef struct A{int x;} A;` and `typedef struct {int x;} A;`, you can use `A a;` to define an object in the same way, then the answer is yes.

Comment: That was my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this declaration

```
typedef struct{
    int data;
    Node *next;
}Node;
```

there is declared an unnamed structure with the  typedef name `Node` and there is used the undeclared name `Node` within the structure declaration. So the compiler should issue a message for this record

```
    Node *next;
```

The name `Node` in this record is undefined.

The problem with such a typedef declaration of an unnamed structure is that you can not refer to the structure itself within its declaration.

Comment: So when used in main(), is 'Node <name>' the exact same thing as 'struct Node <name>'?

Comment: @FirstTree For the first structure declaration it is correct. For the second structure declafration the compiler will issue an error relative to the structure declaration because the used name Node within the structure declaration is not yet defined.